# Struts2 sj:head with scriptPath

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a web application made with Struts2 .
I'm using struts2-Jquery plugin.

With this setting in the jsp head section:

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
   <head>
   <sj:head/>
   </head>
```

Everything is fine, the generated HTML code looks like this:

```
<script src="/MyContextRoot/struts/js/base/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Regarding to the API: 
https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag
If I change the sj:head to it:

```
<sj:head scriptPath="/MyContextRoot/MySubDir/struts/"/>
```

Then the generated code will looks like this (as it expected):

```
<script src="/MyContextRoot/MySubDir/struts/js/base/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

But this request gives me a 404 error from the server.

I can create the directories, and put in the required js files, but I want, that these request would be served by Struts. As it worked in the first case.

My Struts2 filter is mapped to: /*

```
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any idea?

Thanks, 
zsom

Comment: You are changing the script path and NOT putting the files in this path, and expecting this to work?

Comment: With no path, and no files in the MyContextRoot/struts folder, struts can serve them from the struts2-jquery-plugin.jar.

Comment: I need a kind of setting to tell Struts, that request coming to /MyContextRoot/MySubDir/struts are belongs to the jquery plugin, and serve the from the jar

Comment: Where the scripts are situated?

Comment: Normally the scripts are in the struts2-jquery-plugin.jar.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Because only /MyContextRoot/MySubDir is accessible from internet due to a firewall config. And finally why not???

Comment: How do you accessing your application if only `/MyContextRoot/MySubDir` is accessible?

Comment: Everything under '/MyContextRoot/MySubDir' is accessible. So my actions mapped like this: '/MyContextRoot/MySubDir/login.action'

Comment: @zsom I think the question is "why do you want to not serve the file from the S2jQ jar?"

Comment: @DaveNewton: because this is how the sj tablib works by default. I only wanted to change the path. And it is possible, check my answer below.

Comment: @zsom I'm asking *why* do you want to serve it from somewhere else? I'm not saying it's not possible to *change* it--I can read.

Comment: "Because only /MyContextRoot/MySubDir is accessible from internet due to a firewall config"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I extended the org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultStaticContentLoader class, and after I put a constant in struts.xml, to use my class for static content loading.

First create your Loader. You have to override two methods: canHandle, and findStaticResource.

```
public class MyStaticLoader extends DefaultStaticContentLoader{
 ...
 public boolean canHandle(String resourcePath) {
   return superCanHandle || resourcePath.contains("MySubDir/struts");
 }

 public void findStaticResource(String path, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     if(path != null && path.startsWith("/MySubDir/struts")){
        path = path.substring(9);
     }
     super.findStaticResource(path, request, response); 
 }
}
```

In struts.xml just add this class as staticContentLoader.

```
<constant name="struts.staticContentLoader" value="hu.nebih.hfnyportal.util.HFNyPublicStaticLoader"/>
```

That's all.

For me it's more than enough.